# How to check if a bitmap (or canvas) is empty in Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have to implement a function that return to me a boolean if a bitmap or canvas is empty in Android.

How I can do this ?

I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work:

```
Bitmap emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getConfig());
if (myBitmap.sameAs(emptyBitmap)) {
    // myBitmap is empty/blank
}
```

[How to check if a Bitmap is empty (blank) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767466/how-to-check-if-a-bitmap-is-empty-blank-on-android)

Another solution that I have considerated is:

[Fastest way to check if an image is all white or all transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832699/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-image-is-all-white-or-all-transparent)

But I can't check every pixels, I spend so much time in this operation

Comment: What do you mean by empty?

Comment: I need to know is the bitmap is blank

Comment: If i am correct, you need to check if user draw on canvas/bitmap or not.right?

Comment: Yes :) I have a surfaceView where the user can draw, in a second time the draw is converted in bitmap. if bitmap is not empty i want save it, else no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it's so late apparently the best way to do this is to create a bitmap and check if it's the same so `boolean Res (bitmap.sameAs())`

Comment: Bitmap emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getConfig());
if (myBitmap.sameAs(emptyBitmap)) {
    // myBitmap is empty/blank
}