# How to check if drawing layout is empty?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am using [this](https://github.com/ajithvgiri/Canvas-Library) library for make some drawing but I would be able to check if the field is empty ( so no drawing is in the layout ).

Because I'm printing the drawable on a thermal printer and if someone make no drawable is just wastes the paper.

Here is my method `onClick` where I get the drawable from the layout and set it to a bitmap:

```
 parentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

 bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(parentView.getDrawingCache(),510, 360, false);
 BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Comment: how would you check the field is empty?

Comment: @Lucefer oh i don't know how could i, so that's why i'm asking it here

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538007/4342876

Comment: can you set a flag to true whenever user interacts with your view and use its value to determine the chagnes?

Comment: @abhilnair yet tryed it and it's not working with the library i'm using.

Comment: @KaranMer this would be a nice solution but how can i set a listener or check if the user has interacted with the layout?

Comment: I checked the library you have used, you will need to edit `CanvasView` class and set flag over there and create a method using which you can access value of that flag.

Answer (score 1):

`BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap)` check size of bitmap before print. Most probably it could be zero approximately zero for empty drawable. Check it and pops dialog yes, no with a message like "seems like you print empty drawing". If user select yes print it. otherwise, cancel the operation

Comment: by doing this the value is always 734400

Comment: then u can do it. for size 734400. if it has 734400 then pops message like above mentioned. It will save users as well when it contains any drawing with that size

Comment: the point is even if there is a drawable the value is still 734400 so that make no sense

Comment: are checking after drawing ?? It should be increased.

Comment: you can create an empty bitmap using your lib and compare it with the current bitmap as well.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120439/comparing-bitmap-images-in-android will help to find compare it